# jQuery onclick not hiding div

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

  $('.box-wrap').bind("click",function(){
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').bind('click',function(){
          $(this).removeClass('flipped');
        });
    });  
      return false;
});
```

If I re-clicked the div it works, but the second time I click another div the whole script doesn't work. No signs either in console or errors. I'm new to jQuery and can't figure this out.

```
$(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
```

this code works but it's not what i'm looking for. please help

Comment: Try using `live('click', function(){})` instead of `bind('click', function(){})`

Comment: can you show your html structure is this siblings or???? let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `.toggleClass` method (described [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)). Right now, after you have clicked the box the second time it has two event handlers on it - one to add the class `flipped` on click, the other to remove it. It executes first one, then the other, then adds a new handler to remove it on every new click.

You can simplify this greatly by using a single handler, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box-wrap').bind("click",function(){
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do:

```
$(this).find('.card').toggleClass("flipped");
```

i.e.

```
$('.box-wrap').bind("click",function(){
   $(this).find('.card').toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

  $('.box-wrap').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');

        });
    },
      function(){
      $(this).find('.card').removeClass('flipped');
});
```